# UILongPressGestureRecognizer dont track touch when getting out of UIView

Tags: ios

iam using UILongPressGestureRecognizer to track touches inside UIView thats my code

```
-(void)tapGes:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
CGPoint location=[tapGesture locationInView:self.view];
UIView *view=tapGesture.view;
switch (tapGesture.state)
{
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        NSLog(@"enter");
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        NSLog(@"ended");
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        if (location.x>view.frame.size.width ||
            location.y>view.frame.size.height)
        {
            NSLog(@"out");
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"change");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

what i want to do when the touch in state UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged get out of the UIView i dont track it anymore so that i dont get to the state UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always add an extra view to the hierarchy and add the gesture to that view. This would give you the ability to track the gestures location and check it against the frame of the subview. What I mean is, if your current view is 100x100 points, you could make a transparent parent view for it that is 120x120 points. Add the gesture to the 120 point view, and then compare the location of the gesture against the frame of the views first subview.

```
-(void)tapGes:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    CGPoint location=[tapGesture locationInView:tapGesture.view];
    UIView *view = tapGesture.view;

    switch (tapGesture.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            NSLog(@"enter");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            NSLog(@"ended");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            if (CGRectContainsPoint([view.subviews[0] frame], location)) {
                // location is within view
            }else{
                // location has exited view
            }
            NSLog(@"change");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```